# Recommendation/personlization algorithm conflict

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I'm trying to build a recommendation engine for an e-commerce site. By using the common recomendation approach, I'm assuming that each product I recommend has the same value, so all I need to do is optimize the conversion rate probably using a common recomendation algorithm, but when the product's price varry a lot, what I really need to optimize is the following formula for each user:

Value of recomendation = (probability to convert) * (product price)

The bigger problem than choosing the right algorthm and approach is choosing the right metric, so I could compare the different algorithms. For example, If you would like to only optimize the conversion rate, I would use the precision and recall or false/positive metrics.

What metrics and approches/algorithms are recommended in this case?

Comment: What are the priorities of the site-owner? How does the site owner value getting 1 major purchase versus consistent smaller purchase from a customer?

Comment: The higher the price of the product multiplied by the conversion rate, the higher the value of the recommendation is. So it's not only the showing the highest priced products

Comment: Couldn't you just do the regular recall/precision/F1 score calculations, but instead of counting each false positive, correct negative etc. as 1, you could weigh by the value of the product. So if you correctly predict a true positive on 3 products valued 5, 12 and 17 euro's each, you could count that as 34 true positive, instead of 3 true positive.